# HTTP connection to localhost fails

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, ipv6

I have a Java application that makes REST requests to a Jetty server.

It works if I connect to the server with a real DNS name but I get the following exception when I want to make requests to my local testing instance on localhost:

```
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.hasEntity(ClientResponse.java:480) ~[jersey-client-1.14.jar:1.14]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler.handle(ApacheHttpClientHandler.java:182) ~[jersey-apache-client-1.14.jar:1.14]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:435) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(FilterInputStream.java:226) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(FilterInputStream.java:226) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.hasEntity(ClientResponse.java:464) ~[jersey-client-1.14.jar:1.14]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Requests in the browser and with my REST tool work.

I got it to work when I use the IPv6 address for localhost: `https://[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]/`

It always worked for me with localhost. Is it possible that some Java or Windows 7 update changed a default setting so it uses IPv6 instead?

What can I do to make localhost work again and do I need to be worried that this might cause a problem on other PCs when they want to connect to our real server?

I would like to be IPv4 and IPv6 compatible.

edit: here is my hosts file (it is unedited)

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: `StreamClosed` is not caused by a failure to connect. Something at the other end closed the already-open connection.

Comment: Please look on 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023523/bind-jetty-to-ipv6-address

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found the problem. Apparently Skype uses port 80 and 443 as alternative ports.
As soon as I quit Skype everything worked.

[WebApp accessible via localhost but not 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365431/webapp-accessible-via-localhost-but-not-127-0-0-1)

It probably worked with the IPv6 localhost address because Skype doesn't bind to that one.